# Some of Bootstrap3 glyphicons are not displayed correctly on phonegap android webview

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Please have a look at [this attached screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53674497/Screenshot_2013-10-17-10-43-09.png).
It is my PhoneGap testing app - taken on a Galaxy S4.

You should see that the bell, bookmark, briefcase, and camera icons (and more) are not displayed as expected.

Here are my observations:

1. All icons can be displayed correctly in browsers (chrome, safari), on both PC and mobile devices
2. All icons can be displayed correctly in the same app for ios (checked in iphone/ipad, ios7)

The "question mark" can only be seen in an Android app.

Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: I have seen the same issue on my GS3. Havent found a way to fix it yet other than picking a different icon.

Comment: I have the same problem to display question mark in firefox and chrome.

Comment: I landed here with a similar (yet not the same) issue with Desktop Chrome 34. I was using a scaffolded MVC5 app that includes Bootstrap 3.0.0, **upgrading the Bootstrap NuGet package** to 3.1.1 solved my problems.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**It's a problem with the escape sequences.** If you can reliably maintain a UTF-8 encoded CSS file, you could override the Bootstrap defaults to use the actual, non-escaped glyphs.

(Depending on your browser, the following code will appear to contain a bunch of boxes. Copying the code and pasting it into a UTF-8 document should preserve the values, though.)

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.glyphicon-bell:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-calendar:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-camera:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-fire:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-lock:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-wrench:before {
  content: "";
}
```

You can also change the escape sequences to workaround this problem, but browser support varies. If you're only targeting Android/BlackBerry, the following should work fine:

```
.glyphicon-bell:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd14";
}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd16";
}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcbc";
}
.glyphicon-calendar:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcc5";
}
.glyphicon-camera:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcf7";
}
.glyphicon-fire:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd25";
}
.glyphicon-lock:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd12";
}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcce";
}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before {
  content: "\d83d\dccc";
}
.glyphicon-wrench:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd27";
}
```

Comment: Your first part worked perfectly !!! Thanks. "camera" icon is still displayed as a "question mark" in chrome by using 2nd part.

Comment: I fixed the mistake with the CSS for .glyphicon-camera. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Tried the first part, and couldn’t believe the glyphs actually appeared in terminal vim. Made my day :)

Comment: thanx...wordked nicely.

Comment: I have this problem on Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m

Comment: also on 32.0.1700.102 m

Comment: +1 Kudos for noticing this problem. The above CSS fix works great.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of mismatch between version of  bootstrap min .css file and glyph files.