# Bootstrap 3 glyphicons not displaying correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am using Bootstrap 3's glyphicons on a website. It works fine across browsers but not on certain devices as it shows up as a question mark.

I found this fix: [Some of Bootstrap3 glyphicons are not displayed correctly on phonegap android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417040/some-of-bootstrap3-glyphicons-are-not-displayed-correctly-on-phonegap-android-we/19443169#19443169) which fixes the problem on the devices but now the glyphicon is not working in Firefox. (I am overriding the Bootstrap defaults to use the actual, non-escaped glyphs in my CSS.) I was wondering if there is a way to write some jquery using a browser detection for Firefox to remove the override in my CSS file and revert it back to Bootstrap's CSS.

I found this jQuery plugin for browser detection: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Code:
JS

```
if ( $.browser.mozilla ) {
    $('a#calendar span').removeClass('glyphicon-calendar');
    $('a#calendar span').css({'glyphicon-calendar:before': 'content: "\1f4c5"'});
    }
```

CSS to override Bootstrap

```
/* fix glyph not showing on some devices--override the Bootstrap defaults to use the actual, non-escaped glyphs */ 
.glyphicon-calendar:before { 
  content: "\d83d\dcc5";
  }
```

Bootstrap's CSS

```
.glyphicon-calendar:before {
content: "\1f4c5";
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Bootstrap glyphicon not showing in Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659094/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-showing-in-form/35660280#35660280)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `.glyphicon-nonescaped` class, to allow you to switch between default escaped and non-escaped glyphs :

### HTML

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar glyphicon-nonescaped"></i>
```

### CSS

```
.glyphicon-nonescaped.glyphicon-calendar:before { 
    content: "\d83d\dcc5";
}
```

### jQuery

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
    $('.glyphicon-nonescaped').removeClass('glyphicon-nonescaped');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution above works great for various OS. You might add this code to your `css` file and it might work for no-device codes:

```
.glyphicon-bell:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd14";
}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd16";
}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcbc";
}
.glyphicon-calendar:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcc5";
}
.glyphicon-camera:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcf7";
}
.glyphicon-fire:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd25";
}
.glyphicon-lock:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd12";
}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before {
  content: "\d83d\dcce";
}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before {
  content: "\d83d\dccc";
}
.glyphicon-wrench:before {
  content: "\d83d\dd27";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using Javascript, you can use media queries in the CSS instead:

For **Firefox:**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
         .glyphicon-nonescaped.glyphicon-calendar:before {
             content: "\d83d\dcc5";
         }
    }
```

For **IE 8+:**

```
@media screen\0 { 
       .glyphicon-nonescaped.glyphicon-calendar:before {
           content: "\d83d\dcc5";
       }
}
```